Ionic Angular Firebase phone authentication. Firebase idToken need to be added in heders eachtime for authenticated customers
I am trying to use firebase phone authentication in my ionic angular app. I am loving in to the app using firebase authentication at the beginning. After that, I do not want Customer need to login again and again. So I am checking if the user already logged in then get the new idToken for the customer. I need to pass the idToken as "FireBaseIdToken" in the backend service headers. printIdToken() function is printing the new toke perfectly. When I am trying to use callIdToken(), it is calling asynchronous way. I want it to wait for promis to complete then the returned value should be added in the header. I tried to use await inside callIdToken() , but it is not waiting for the promise. It need to wait for promise.

import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Auth, onAuthStateChanged } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthinterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private auth: Auth) { }
  intercept(req, next) {
    console.log("Request URL:: : " + req.url);
    let tokenizedReq;

    if (req.url.includes("/auth/customer/")) {
      console.log(" callIdToken start");
      //this.printIdToken();

      const idToken =  this.callIdToken();
      console.log("IdToken :",idToken);
      console.log("callIdToken Completed");
      tokenizedReq = req.clone(
        {
          headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('actualToken'))
            .set('FireBaseIdToken', 'FireBase ' + idToken)
        }
      )
    } else {
      tokenizedReq = req.clone(
        {
          headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('actualToken'))
        }
      )
    }
    return next.handle(tokenizedReq)
  }

  async callIdToken() {
    onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {
        return this.auth.currentUser.getIdToken();
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  }

  async printIdToken()
  {
      console.log("Inside Service4");
      onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.auth.currentUser.getIdToken()
            .then((confirmationResult) => {
              console.log(confirmationResult);            
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.error("Error :", error);
            });
        } else {
          console.log("logged out");

          // User is signed out
          // ...
        }
      });
  }
}


USING await
=============

`  callIdToken(){
     onAuthStateChanged(this.auth, (user) => {
      if (user) {  
        console.log("Testing");
       const token = async () =>{
        console.log("In side Testing");
        return await this.auth.currentUser.getIdToken();
        }
        console.log("Testing",token);
      }});
  }


